# Perl WWW::Mechanize (or LWP) get redirect url

Tags: perl, url, redirect, www-mechanize, lwp

So I am using `WWW::Mechanize` to crawl sites. It works great, except if I request a url such as:

```
http://www.levi.com/
```

I am redirected to:

```
http://us.levi.com/home/index.jsp
```

And for my script I need to know that this redirect took place and what the url I was redirected to is. Is there anyway to detect this with `WWW::Mechanize` or `LWP` and then get the redirected url? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use URI;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $url = 'http://...';
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(autocheck => 0);
$mech->max_redirect(0);
$mech->get($url);

my $status = $mech->status();
if (($status >= 300) && ($status < 400)) {
  my $location = $mech->response()->header('Location');
  if (defined $location) {
    print "Redirected to $location\n";
    $mech->get(URI->new_abs($location, $mech->base()));
  }
}
```

If the status code is **3XX**, then you should check response headers for redirection url.

Comment: If I wanted to allow redirects again, or like reset the redirect count, is there a way I could do that? Or for instance, could I follow a string of redirects to their final location and still know that the status was between 300 and 400? I got rid of max_redirect(0), but then I just got a status of 500 and I know that's not right...

Comment: if anyone looks at this for reference, simply storing a new WWW::Mechanize object in $mech does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get to the same place by inspecting the `redirects()` method on the response object.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use WWW::Mechanize;

my $ua = WWW::Mechanize->new;
my $res = $ua->get('http://metacpan.org');

my @redirects = $res->redirects;
say 'request uri: ' . $redirects[-1]->request->uri;
say 'location header: ' . $redirects[-1]->header('Location');
```

Prints:

```
request uri: http://metacpan.org
location header: https://metacpan.org/
```

See https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response#$r-%3Eredirects  Keep in mind that more than one redirect may have taken you to your current location.  So you may want to inspect every response which is returned via `redirects()`.