# Get redirected url in perl

Tags: perl, url, get

I want to get last of redirect URL.

like

url_1 : http://on.fb.me/4VGeu
url_2 : https://www.facebook.com/

I want to get url_2 by url_1 in perl.
Previous source is below.

```
sub get_redirect_location
{
    my ($url) = @_;
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

    $ua->proxy('http', 'SAMPLE_PROXY');
    my $req = new HTTP::Request(GET => $url);
    my $res = $ua->request($req);

    return $res->headers_as_string;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the request that lead to a response using

```
$response->request()
```

You can get the previous response in the chain using

```
$response->previous()
```

All together:

```
while ($response) {
   say $response->request()->uri();
   $response = $response->previous();
}
```

Comment: Does this still work when there are more than 2 "redirecting sites" ?

Comment: @Ibrahim Apachi, Yeah, the loop shows you all the URLs that were requested.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at WWW::Mechanize.  I have used it before to do something like this.
http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#$mech->redirect_ok()

You may also find this post helpful:

[Perl WWW::Mechanize (or LWP) get redirect url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922054/perl-wwwmechanize-or-lwp-get-redirect-url)